# MVC Login page doesnt go to correct return url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am working on a simple home website with a single username/password combo. I dont want user to register, etc. However, i believe I have backed myself into a corner. I modified the account controller to look for username "x" and password "y" and return success. it does that fine. The returnUrl has the correct folder ("/movie" in this case). But it just stays on the login page with a url like while loading:

> http://blah.org/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FMovie

then it goes to the error page, with the same url in the address bar.

Here is my Login function:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, "", model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    if (model.Password == "y" && model.UserName == "x")
    {
       result = SignInStatus.Success;
    }

    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

It does drop down to the "Success" statement, the to redirect to local:

```
private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

goes into Redirect("/Movie")

Maybe if there was a way to make a username/password in the local store....I don't know

ADDITION: I put a breakpoint on the controller class and it hits it, but never goes into the Index() method

Comment: did you put break point on `switch(result)` and see where it takes you? or you can look into or show us `RedirectToLocal` function.

Comment: Do you have a moviecontroller with an index method?

Comment: Yes, It all worked fine for testing the page with the [Authorize] attribute off